# How to use CeleryExecutor in airflow without using mysql

Tags: redis, celery, airflow

My backend is `redis`, but the `airflow.cfg` file shipped in the airflow package only gave example on using `mysql` as backend for `CeleryExecutor`. Basically not sure how to set/replace the following `sql_alchemy_conn` in `airflow.cfg` for `redis` backend.

```
sql_alchemy_conn = sqlite:////Users/myself/airflow/airflow.db
```

Tried googling by no luck.

Any sample `airflow.cfg` to use redis as backend for CeleryExecutor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "sql_alchemy_conn" is used for the meta database dealing with DAG runs and such.

I'm guessing you want to set the following for redis to be backend for Celery

```
[core]
executor = CeleryExecutor
...
[celery]
broker_url = redis://BROKER_URL/...
celery_result_backend = redis://BROKER_URL/...
```